# Getting error due to column name of my database table is "from"

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, ado.net

my database column name is "from" but am getting error while i change the column name to other name error is not occuring.why?

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Mycon"].ConnectionString);
    con.Open();
    string qry="insert into Mynew(name,age,from,address,job)values(@name,@age,@from,@address,@job)";
    SqlCommand cmd= new SqlCommand(qry, con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", TextBox1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", TextBox2.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@from",TextBox3.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", TextBox4.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@job", TextBox5.Text);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    }
```

when i change column name to city am not getting error why is it happening?

Comment: From is reserved, cannot be used as a column nane

Comment: How you are changing column name?

Comment: by editing dtabase table column name.

Comment: [check this link](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/26/sql-server-how-to-rename-a-column-name-or-table-name/) if you are using SQL Server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`from` is a reserved keyword in SQL. If you want to use it as a table name, you have to escape it by:

- putting it between backticks (MySQL and others)
- putting it between square brackets (MS Access, SQL server)

---

So either

```
insert into Mynew(name,age,`from`,address,job)values(@name,@age,@from,@address,@job)
```

or

```
insert into Mynew(name,age,[from],address,job)values(@name,@age,@from,@address,@job)
```

depending on the database you're using.

To avoid confusion, it's obviously better to use a different column name.

Comment: What database are you using? SQL Server?